# How do I check for spawn_id that's alive? (TCL)

Tags: tcl, expect

I spawn a telnet process to a host. I send a command, expect something
in return. This goes on for a while. But somewhere in between this
interaction, the connection to the host is lost mysteriously and my
script dies while trying to "send" something to the spawned (now dead)
telnet process.
I'd like to write a procedure that takes the spawn id and the command
to be sent as arguments. I'd like to check if the spawn id exists
(i.e., the connection between the program and the host exists) before I
"send" the command. Otherwise, I'd like to exit.
Something like this:

```
proc Send {cmd sid} {
if { $sid is not dead yet } { ;## don't know how to do this
part
send -i $sid "$cmd\r"
} else {
puts "channel id: $sid does not exist anymore. Exiting"
exit
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than checking if the spawned process is still alive, you could `catch` the error that `send` raises when sending to a dead process:

```
proc Send {cmd sid} {
    if {[catch {send -i $sid "$cmd\r"} err]} {
        puts "error sending to $sid: $err"
        exit
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah i am using the same catch and err method as of now. but here i don't want to come out .. if a spawn_id is not alive i would like to open a another telnet session again to the same server and then send the command.

Comment: @Tanuj Instead of a simple “complain and exit” you want to reconnect? So you replace the `puts` and `exit` in that code with a reconnect and then you try to `send` the command again. Except you've now got to change the outside world's knowledge of the `sid` too… it's starting to get very messy; looks like you've got an imperfect factoring of the interface.

Comment: Just an FYI: There is an extra "}" in the "if" statement above which results in 'args: should be "proc name args body"' error. StackOverflow, in it's infinite wisdom will not allow me to make a 1 character edit to the original answer.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem before and used the Mac/Linux `ps` command to do that:

```
if {[catch {exec ps $pid} std_out] == 0} { 
    puts "Alive"
} else {
    puts "It's dead, Jim"
}
```

If you are using Windows, I heard that the tlist.exe command does something similar, but I don't have a Windows machine to test it out.